# How to print set(STL) which has pair(STL) as its data type?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to show my answer to the user. My answer is in Check_Answer SET(STL). Whose declaration is as follows:

```
typedef pair<int,int> Ans;
set<Ans>Check_Answer;
```

Now I am passing it to a function to display the answer and it looks like this:

```
void showanswer(set<Ans>Check_Answer){
    set<Ans>::const_iterator itr;
    cout<<"Answer:"<<endl;
    for(itr = Check_Answer.begin();itr!=Check_Answer.end();itr++){
        cout<<itr->first<<" "<<itr->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to display the answer.

Expected Output should be like:

0 0

0 1

0 2

1 2
...

Basically, printing int values which are indexes of a matrix.

A snippet of function where Check_Answer is used :

```
 void tracePath(cell cellDetails[][COL], Pair dest, int grid[][COL],Pair src )
{
int x_cor,y_cor=51;
    printf ("\nThe Path is ");
    int row = dest.first;
    int col = dest.second;

    stack<Pair> Path;

    while (!(cellDetails[row][col].parent_i == row
            && cellDetails[row][col].parent_j == col ))
    {
        Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
        int temp_row = cellDetails[row][col].parent_i;
        int temp_col = cellDetails[row][col].parent_j;
        row = temp_row;
        col = temp_col;
    }
    int ans;
    Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
    set<Ans>Answer;
    set<Ans>Check_Answer;
    while (!Path.empty())
    {
        pair<int,int> p = Path.top();
        Path.pop();
        Check_Answer.insert(make_pair(p.first,p.second));
    }
    int i,x,y,Key;
    int a= src.first, b=src.second;
    cout<<"You have \x03 Lifelines"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter -1,-1 to terminate answer"<<endl;
    while(true){
            cin>>Key;
            if(Key==0)
                a=b=-1;
            else if(Key==8){
                a=a-1;
            }
            else if(Key==2){
                a=a+1;
            }
            else if(Key==6){
                b=b+1;
            }
            else if(Key==4){
                b=b-1;
            }
            else if(Key==9){
                a=a-1;
                b=b+1;
            }
            else if(Key==7){
                a=a-1;
                b=b-1;
            }
            else if(Key==3){
                a=a+1;
                b=b+1;
            }
            else if(Key==1){
                a=a+1;
                b=b-1;
            }

            if(a==-1 && b==-1){
               break;
                }
            else if(grid[a][b]==0){
                cout<<"You cannot make IAF jets flyover pakistan governed territory!!\n";
                y_cor+=2;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                x=9*b;
               y=3+(5*a);
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
               gotoxy(x,y);
               cout<<"\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1";
               y++;
            }
                gotoxy(0,y_cor);
                Answer.insert(make_pair(a,b));
            }
        }
    if(Answer == Check_Answer)
        cout<<"BOOM BOOM BOOM!!\n\nJ-e-M camp has been eradicated."<<endl;
    else {
        cout <<"Oops This was no brainer dude! Anyway Try again next time :p"<<endl;
        cout<<"Do you want to know the answer(Y/N):"<<endl;
        cin>>ans;
        if(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')
         showanswer(Check_Answer);
    }
}
```

When I enter correct values there is no problem but when i try to display the answer, values are not printed.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? What output is your code producing?

Comment: Psychic debugging: you are also passing `Check_Answer` by value to a function to populate your set, so `showanswer` is receiving a copy of an empty set

Comment: I am sorry but i did not get what you are trying to explain me @Caleth

Comment: do you have a function like `void calculateanswer(set<Ans>Check_Answer)`?

Comment: @SaumyaPandey Basically what Caleth is saying is that this code is OK, the reason it doesn't print the right values is that you have a bug in another part of your code. But since we can't see that code it's hard to help.

Comment: Nop @caleth, There a function which calculates the answer, declaration and initialization of Check_Answer is within it. I do not pass Check_Answer to a function to calculate the answer.

Comment: @SaumyaPandey It would help if you say what output you see instead, and also to show the code where you populate the set and pass it to the printing function.

Comment: @SaumyaPandey So, based on latest edit, maybe `Path` is empty and so nothing gets into your set, or maybe `Path` has the wrong values and so you see the wrong output. You have a bug somewhere but until we see more code and get a better description of what you can see, it's going to be hard to solve this problem.

Comment: I would start by calling `showanswer(Answer)` as well as `showanswer(Check_Answer)`. Note also that you are discarding the path order, so you may as well just insert directly into `Check_Answer`